# a (the) rapidly growing number of

Tags: articles, determiners

A quote from The Economist ([Higher education: The attack of the MOOCs](http://www.economist.com/news/business/21582001-army-new-online-courses-scaring-wits-out-traditional-universities-can-they?spc=scode&spv=xm&ah=9d7f7ab945510a56fa6d37c30b6f1709)):

> The new money should allow Coursera to build on any advantage it has
>   from being a first mover among **a** rapidly growing number of MOOC
>   providers.

I'd like to know, would it be OK to change it to

> The new money should allow Coursera to build on any advantage it has
>   from being a first mover among **the** rapidly growing number of MOOC
>   providers.

P.S. Does the indefinite article before "first mover" indicate that Coursera is "one of the first movers", but not the very first?

Comment: _a number of providers_ means  many providers. _a large number of, a growing number of,...._ also means many. On the other hand, _the number of the providers_ means how many of the providers. Therefore, **a rapidly growing number of providers** is correct in the given context.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't catch the difference, Jay. "..the number of MOOC providers" means "..how many of MOOC providers"?

Comment: @CopperKettle It means if you have 10 MOOC providers, `the number of MOOC providers` is 10. It refers to the number, not the (group of) providers. A number = many, not specifying how many (1,2,3,...) providers there are.

Comment: Thanks a million, Fantaiser. Gotta jot this down somewhere and jury-rig some self test on this distinction. "A first mover.. among the quantity of providers" should sound crazy to the native speaker.

Answer (score 2):

"A number of" means *several*.

> We have discussed the matter on a number of occasions.

It could also mean *some*.

> A number of problems have arisen.

In your case, it means *several*. The author is using "a number of" because is trying to give state two facts:

- There are several MOOC providers that did something
- The number of MOOC providers doing that is rapidly growing

Comment: Thanks, Kiamlauno! I know of the "a number of"-"several" equivalence.       Would a definite article really wreck the "a number of" construct so hard that it would no longer mean "a small group (=several) of" and become illogical?

Comment: The idiomatic expression is "a number of" not "the number of." Replace _a_ with _the_ in both the example sentences I shown, and the meaning changes. (Whenever a native speaker would still understand the sentences is another matter.) You could say "I cannot count the number of times I told you _no_." but that has a different meaning.

Comment: I wonder if the intercalating "rapidly growing" combo hadn't broken the idiom in the first place. Maybe here the author does not intend to use the idiom but merely means "a rapidly growing group of.." Google Books finds instances of "among **the** growing number of..", such as: `'Ill health among the growing number of younger adults places a very significant burden on health and social care.'` (2012, Anita Fatchett, _Social Policy for Nurses_).